# Can someone explain C# CngKey.Create please?

Tags: c#, security, encryption

The internet resources seem few and far between and the best MSDN page (as far as I could tell) throws an error!

Specifically, I'm not sure what to create as a CngKeyCreationParameters object...

Comment: MSDN does not have an error for me on these two pages:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngkeycreationparameters.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359322.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CngKey :** `CngKey` objects contain properties.
 Some properties must be added to a key when it is created. Other properties
can be added after the key is created.

**CngKeyCreationParameters**:
The `CngKeyCreationParameters` class enables you to add properties to a key as it is being created.

**your problem:** `I'm not sure what to create as a CngKeyCreationParameters object`

here is how to do do this

---

```
//  Create CngKeyCreationParameters 
CngKeyCreationParameters keyParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters();

// set properties accordingly
keyParams.ExportPolicy =  CngExportPolicies.AllowArchiving;
keyParams.KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey;
keyParams.Provider = new CngProvider("someprovider");

// here is how to use keyParams 
CngKey mycngKey =  
       CngKey.Create(new CngAlgorithm(""), "keyName", keyParams);
```